# How to plot standard error in tensorboard line plots

Tags: python, tensorboard

Is it possible to generate line plots with standard error in Tensorboard?

It would be enough to plot three separate lines and using something similar to `matplotlib.fill_between`, or in the worst of the cases, plotting vertical error bars.